# Yii2 module (not under /vendor folder) class not found in config/main.php

Tags: reflection, module, yii2

I've created a module under folder api (which itself is same level as backend & frontend in yii2 advanced app).

Folder structure:

> api
>   -- common
>   ------ controllers
>   ------ models
>   -- config
>   -- modules
>   ------ v1
>   ---------- controllers
>   ---------- models
>   -- runtime
>   -- tests
>   -- web

In api/config/main.php:

```
return [
'id' => 'app-api',
'basePath' => dirname(__DIR__),    
'bootstrap' => ['log'],
'modules' => [
    'v1' => [
        'basePath' => '@app/modules/v1',
        'class' => 'api\modules\v1\Module'
    ]
],
```

I get error:

> ReflectionException
>
> Class api\modules\v1\Module does not exist

The class is definitely there.

I've run a composer dumpautoload (no errors).

urlManager in config/main.php:

```
'urlManager' => [
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'enableStrictParsing' => true,
        'showScriptName' => false,
        'rules' => [
              'v1/site/index' => 'v1/site/index', //module/controller/action
        ],        
    ]
```

Any help much appreciated,

thanks

Comment: Check if namespace in this `Module.php` file is correct. Also double check the path for case sensitivity differences.

Comment: You dont need a `basePath` option, just `'v1'     => [
            'class' => 'api\modules\v1\Module',
        ],`

Comment: Have you set correct alias for '@app' ? I mean for API it should point to api directory.

Comment: Bizley - Namespace of Module.php:  namespace api\modules\v1;  (seems OK?)

Yupik - I've removed basePath entry, still get same error

witzawitz - Hmmm don't think you need to explicitly set @app (isn't that determined automatically by the framework?) If not, where to set it?


Still getting same error ... :(

Comment: Btw this is the project I am basing it off: https://github.com/deerawan/yii2-advanced-api  

I basically copied the api folder and made minor changes to fit with my system.

Answer (score 8):

OK got it:
in common/config/bootstrap.php, add:

```
Yii::setAlias('@api', dirname(dirname(__DIR__)) . '/api');
```

Then in config/main.php use:

```
'modules' => [
        'v1' => [
            'basePath' => '@api/modules/v1',
            'class' => 'api\modules\v1\Module'
        ]
    ],
```

This seems to work, thanks guys

Comment: or in config.php ```'aliases' => [
        '@api' => dirname(dirname(__DIR__)) . '/api'
    ], ```

and ``` 'basePath' => '@api/modules/v1', ``` is not needed

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, gvanto. Also check whether you include common/config/bootstrap.php in \api\web\index.php . Like here

```
<?php
defined('YII_DEBUG') or define('YII_DEBUG', true);
defined('YII_ENV') or define('YII_ENV', 'dev');

require(__DIR__ . '/../../vendor/autoload.php');
require(__DIR__ . '/../../vendor/yiisoft/yii2/Yii.php');
require (__DIR__ . '/../../common/config/bootstrap.php');

$config = yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::merge(
require(__DIR__ . '/../../common/config/main.php'),
require(__DIR__ . '/../../common/config/main-local.php'),
require(__DIR__ . '/../config/main.php'),
require(__DIR__ . '/../config/main-local.php')
);

$application = new yii\web\Application($config);
$application->run();
```

that was my mistake. Maybe it will help someone