# ReflectionException while trying to add Yii2 module

Tags: php, yii2

I'm trying to add REST api to my existing classic Yii2 (advanced template) project. According to [Creating a REST API for Yii2-basic-template](https://www.diggin-data.de/dd-cms/blog/post/view/id/1004/name/Creating+a+REST+API+for+Yii2-basic-template)
and [RESTful API in Yii 2 Advanced Application Template](https://github.com/deerawan/yii2-advanced-api) I'm trying to achieve that by adding a new module to my existing app.
Here is my application structure now:

```
+ api
  + config
    -main.php
  + modules
    + v1
      + controllers
      -Module.php
  -index.php
  -.htaccess
+ backend
+ common
...
```

My api/config/main.php file:

```
<?php

$params = require(__DIR__ . '/../../backend/config/params.php');

return [
    'id' => 'app-backend-api',
    'basePath' => dirname(__DIR__) . '/..',
    'bootstrap' => ['log'],
    'modules' => [
        'v1' => [
            'class' => 'api\modules\v1\Module'
        ]
    ],
    'components' => [
        'request' => [
            'parsers' => [
                'application/json' => 'yii\web\JsonParser',
            ]
        ],
        'urlManager' => [
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'enableStrictParsing' => true,
            'showScriptName' => false,
            'rules' => [
                ['class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule', 'controller' => ['v1/goal']],
            ],
        ],
    ],
    'params' => $params,
];
```

and my Module.php

```
<?php
namespace api\modules\v1;

class Module extends \yii\base\Module
{
    public $controllerNamespace = 'api\modules\v1\controllers';

    public function init()
    {
        parent::init();
    }
}
```

The problem is that when I try to navigate to http://my-url/api/v1/goals I get the following error:

```
Invalid Configuration – yii\base\InvalidConfigException
Failed to instantiate component or class "api\modules\v1\Module".

Caused by: ReflectionException
Class api\modules\v1\Module does not exist
in C:\wamp64\www\agency\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\di\Container.php at line 453
```

Comment: Looks like problem with autoloader. Do you have defined autoloading rules for `api` namespace in `composer.json`? If not, you should at least define `@api` alias in Yii config.

Comment: Thank you very much.  Adding the alias solved the problem.

Comment: found the answer to your question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41096504/yii2-module-not-under-vendor-folder-class-not-found-in-config-main-php/41116785)

Answer (score 1):

1. Create file common/config/aliases.php:

```
    Yii::setAlias('common', dirname(__DIR__));
    Yii::setAlias('frontend', dirname(dirname(__DIR__)) . '/frontend');
    Yii::setAlias('backend', dirname(dirname(__DIR__)) . '/backend');
    Yii::setAlias('console', dirname(dirname(__DIR__)) . '/console');
    Yii::setAlias('api', dirname(dirname(__DIR__)) . '/api');
```

2. Add this line to file api/web/index.php

```
    require(__DIR__ . '/../../common/config/aliases.php');
```